# Bamboo deployment - add a new environment to every deployment projects

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, bamboo, continuous-deployment

We have a new environment created and we want to configure all Bamboo deployment projects such that the artifact is deployed to that environment. It is too stupid to do it manually by clicking into each of the deployment project and add the new environment - as the only difference is the host name, while all the steps are the same. Is there any smart way to do that?

Comment: Using java BambooSpecs is the way we do that.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, this is not possible with Bamboo itself (i.e., you need to do this in the UI). If you don't mind a plug-in, you could use our [Plan DSL for Bamboo plug-in](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/ch.mibex.bamboo.plandsl/server/overview). Here's how the DSL would look like to accomplish this task (it is basically just Groovy):

```
['PLANKEY-1', 'PLANKEY-2'].each { planKey ->

    project('PROJECTKEY') {
        plan(planKey) {
            deploymentProject("Deployment Project Name") {
                description "Deployment project for plug-in"
                environment("Staging") {
                    description "Your new deployment project"

                    tasks {
                        cleanWorkingDirectory("Clean the working directory") {}
                        artifactDownload("Download release contents") {
                            artifact("plug-in") {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You basically just have to iterate through all your plans and add the deployment project with all its components (triggers, tasks, etc.).

Please note that the plug-in is brand new and that our documentation is not as good as we want it to be.

Cheers,

Michael

Comment: Your plugin looks great and it should really be something come with Bamboo by default (who want to click on the GUI everytime for changing configurations?) Um, the only thing is, it is not free (But I know, your great work deserves something)....

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it was indeed quite an effort :-)